# can we create same object with same name multiple times in c++

Tags: c++

why the following code will not throw error :

suppose we have a class named myclass.

Scenario 1:

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        myclass m;
    }
```

Scenario 2:

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        myclass m(i);
    }
```

Assume we have single argument constructor defined also.
The above two are not throwing error. What's exactly happening in both scenarios.

Comment: scope of `m` ends at `}` , so in next iteration, `myclass m;` creates a new `m`

Comment: An object is created and destroyed inside the scope of the loop multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to print the address of the object, it was same for all object creations. Why its having same address ?

Comment: The memory location is reused. Just like a hotel reuses its rooms for many many customers. Note that the memory location just happens to be reused; it doesn't need to be.

Comment: You should get this information from any book or tutorial that teaches the basics of `C++` programming.

Answer (score 5):

Variable `m` is `local` and for this type of variables `Lifetime` is limited to their `Scope`.

- Scope is the **region or section** of code where a variable can be accessed.
- Lifetime is the time **duration** where an object/variable is in a valid state.

Scope of the variable m ends at the end of the for cycle and so lifetime. So at the beginning of the next iteration, `m` is not in the memory anymore, and there is no conflict caused by same names.

Answer (score -2):

Both Scenario will work fine.

First Scenario:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        myclass m; // default constructor will be called
                   // Memory allocation for object
        /* Some code */
        //destructor will be called at end i.e scope end
        // Memory released for the object
    }
```

Second Scenario:

```
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    myclass m(i);// parametrized constructor will be called.
                 // Memory allocation for object
    /* Some code */
    //destructor will be called at end i.e at scope end.
    // Memory released for the object
}
```

If same memory address is available to allocate the memory for object, You may get the same address every-time, but not necessary

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass{

    public: 
    int i; 
    myclass():i(0){}
    myclass(int x):i(x){}
};

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            myclass m(8); 
            cout<<&m<<endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7ffdf3daec20
0x7ffdf3daec20
0x7ffdf3daec20
0x7ffdf3daec20
0x7ffdf3daec20
```

Comment: "But this not the same case always,that depend on your class data members and type of constructor calls" Since the memory layout or allingnment requirements nor the code of the loop body won't magically change there is practically no way for the memory location being different in any iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Swordfish I mean the address location of object will be different with  default constructor and parametrized constructor

Comment: @HarshGiri your explanation about the memory location being different or not is wrong. The addresses may or may not be different. It's unspecified and you shouldn't rely on this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @Jabberwocky okk thanks I got it

Comment: @Jabberwocky can you tell with some example as I saw same address allocation everytime for all the object in that loop, but different while calling different type of constructor

Comment: @HarshGiri look at the generated assembly code. This is totally platform dependant.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It mean that every time in that loop of object creation, it is possible to get different address

Comment: @HarshGiri yes it is unlikely but possible, but it's not important. You don't need to care.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It check in online compiler, linux system, The result seem to same but address location is different i.e just those hex number. can you tell me how it can be possible if I wanted different address location everytime in that loop

Comment: @HarshGiri you should post a separate question about this topic.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am clear, I don't think so